# image uploads at second click on the browser file button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I uploads image on the image-input, the image did not shows.

But whenever I click second time on the browser file button it shows uploaded image immediately.

Code is given below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.BeginForm()
    {
            <div>
                <img id="UserImage" alt="Image Section" src="" style="width: 148px; height: 148px" />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { @type = "file", @onclick = "ImageUploader(event)" })
            </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
    }
    <script>
        var ImageUploader = function (e) {
            var input = e.target;
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function () {
                var UIHTML = $('#UserImage')[0];
                UIHTML.src = reader.result;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please any body help me its my school assignment. I have not much time

Comment: You may try this.
http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `@onclick = "ImageUploader(event)"` to `@onchange = "ImageUploader(event)"`

Comment: Alexandru-Ionut Mihai thanks now it's done thanks alot

Comment: @TittiTowel Please refer: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/342092)

Comment: Alexandru-Ionut Mihai I tried to vote you but its not accepting my vote. I don't why, I think I am new user and have less reputation for voting

Comment: Alexandru-Ionut Mihai how to follow @Div link..?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: @TittiTowel You cannot give up vote until you not gain 15 reputation points.